# Generate Image or canvas from html dom using react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, reactjs, html2canvas

I have goggled my solutions to **generate Image/Canvas from HTML DOM using JavaScript** Library like "**html2Canvas**", "**dom-to-image**", "**webshot**" etc.

But non of these are generating good quality image with cross browser.

Can anyone have solution to Generate/Capture Image from HTML DOM which have multi browser solution like Chrome/Safar/Firefox/Internet Explorer .

Thanks
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this : https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/tree/master/examples/html2pdf

It's a JS tool to html => pdf. It's using html2canvas. 
The output is a PDF but with perfect image quality.

Html => Canvas => pdf.

If you get the lib source : https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/libs/html2pdf.js

you can easly overwrite :

```
var promise = html2canvas(doc.body, {
    canvas : canvas,
    onrendered : function(canvas) {
        if (callback) {
            if (iframe) {
                iframe.parentElement.removeChild(iframe);
            }
            callback(pdf);
        }
    }
});
```

and try to get only canvas. (in parameters, or in callback, idk).

Anyway, it's not easy but it's all I can do for you.

Comment: Thanks @GreGGus for your valuable feedback on the same. I have gone through the solution you have provided, but its not rendering SVG and Inline images from my html page. It would be great if you guide me to capture all the elements from HTML with its respective CSS styles.